# Transition from Kafka Connect (Docker based) to AWS MSK Connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am using this repo as a reference, and I've successfully got it up and running locally: https://github.com/rhaycock/Kafka-Connect-POC/tree/master/kafka-connect-main

I'm trying to set up a connector in MSK Connect and I am using this sink spec: https://github.com/rhaycock/Kafka-Connect-POC/blob/master/kafka-connect-main/config/sink/gcs-connector.json

There are also a lot of environment variables in the docker-compose.yml file: https://github.com/rhaycock/Kafka-Connect-POC/blob/master/kafka-connect-main/docker-compose.yml

My question at this point, is how do I get all of these variables from the Docker compose file into an MSK connector? Do they go in the "Connector Configuration" in MSK? Or the Worker Configuration? Or somewhere else? Specifically I need ones like `CONNECT_GROUP_ID`, `CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC`, `CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC`, `CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC`, among a few others.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file you linked to are managed by the MSK Connect service

When using MSK Connect you have control over properties in the following locations:

1. Connector configuration
2. Worker configuration (provided the properties in the defined allow-list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html))

Other properties, such as those which dictate how the Connect framework is configured (e.g `KAFKA_CONNECT_MODE` in the `docker-compose` file) are managed by MSK Connect.

Considering the `docker-compose.yml` file you linked, the list below maps the env vars to properties that are customizable in MSK Connect. Properties excluded from this list are currently service managed:

- `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` -> `kafkaCluster.apacheKafkaCluster.bootstrapServers` in the [CreateConnector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/MSKC/latest/mskc/API_CreateConnector.html) request.
- `AWS_ROLE_ARN` -> `serviceExecutionRoleArn` in the [CreateConnector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/MSKC/latest/mskc/API_CreateConnector.html) request.
- `CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC` -> `offset.storage.topic` in a Worker Configuration resource, learn more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html#msk-connect-manage-connector-offsets).

One final note, the `README.md` of the repository you linked also states:

> Copy any required jar files required for CLASSPATH and update the .env with the correct details

In MSK Connect you can achieve this by creating a [Custom Plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-plugins.html) resource with the JARs you want to bundle (e.g your connector implementation)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I figured this much. So some of these properties are customizable, namely the three `*_STORAGE_TOPIC` properties you mentioned, but also the `CONNECT_GROUP_ID`? Can I change that one in the Worker Config? There may be others but I think I get the idea. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I just checked the document you linked...it does make mention of the group ID, thanks again!

Comment: In the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html it lists a bunch of worker properties which are not configurable. Does this mean there is no way to change them when using MSK?

Comment: @SultanofSwing That's correct. If this is blocking a specific use case I'd recommend reaching out to AWS support.